# What is the optimal way to align equations in BEAMER-class?

Tags: beamer, equations, vertical-alignment, alignat

I have encountered many different environment for aligning equations: `align`, `equation`, `alignat`, `gather`, etc.

However, what is the optimal environment to use in a BEAMER-class? More specifically, what achieves:
1. Vertical alignment of different equations across the `frames`, i.e. same starting point on the page
2. Minimal white space below and above equations to enhance the audience's experience.
3. Minimal distance between equation number (left-side) and the equations.

Current code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \abovedisplayskip=8pt
 \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
 \belowdisplayskip=0pt
 \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: about your point 1: With your settings, the content is vertically centred, so the starting point will depend on the amount of content. If you want the same starting points, you could try `\documentclass[leqno,t]{beamer}`

Comment: Personally I disagree with your point 2. A reasonable amount of white space will make it easier to read your equations, both too much and too less are bad.

Comment: About point 3: This probably depends very much on the topic, but I usually don't think that equations numbers are a good idea in a presentation

Comment: You wrote, "I have encountered many different environment[s] for aligning equations: `align`, `equation`, ..." IMNSHO, it seems weird to claim that `equation` environments can be used to align equations, unless the `equation` environments are combined with `split` or `aligned` environments (neither of which you mention). Regarding your first objective: Why on earth would, or should, anyone in the audience of your presentation care about the alignment of equations *across frames*? If you really expect them to notice (let alone care about) such details, you're in for serious disappointment.

Comment: Basically, you need to determine the worst case for the left side and align everything to that.

Comment: OTOH, I assumed you meant horizontal alignment.  To achieve vertical alignment (one equation per frame} you would use \parbox or minipage with the same height above and below the alignment point (centered).

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments! @Mico I agree with your statement, unnecessary perfectionism.

Comment: @samcarter Do you suggest to remove eq. numbers in presentations?

Comment: @Sean Generally speaking: yes. I imagine they can be useful for things like hard-core math lectures but in most cases I would not use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\mathmakebox` to align expressions in any equation environment, in any frame.  As far as I know, only `flalign` will let you align to the left side, though.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not with my editor

%\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \abovedisplayskip=8pt
 \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
 \belowdisplayskip=0pt
 \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newlength{\mylength}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\mylength}{$\displaystyle \left. \frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\right|_{x\in S}$}
\begin{frame}
Some text here.
\begin{flalign}
  \mathmakebox[\mylength][r]{S}&=\lbrace x>0 \rbrace &&
\end{flalign}
some more text
\begin{flalign}
 \left. \frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\right|_{x\in S} &=F(x) &&
\end{flalign}
and finishing with text.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Continued alignment on next frame.
\begin{flalign}
  \mathmakebox[\mylength][r]{S}&=\lbrace x>0 \rbrace &&
\end{flalign}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there an alternative to 'fleqno' global-setting. 'fleqno' achieves the left-alignment, but it does not align with 'leqno'.